# Why NULL string is different than "" string?

Tags: .net, string, c++-cli

What is the difference between the following coding ways:

```
if (String::IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1->Text))
```

and

```
if (TextBox1->Text == "")
```

?

Comment: BTW, why question marked by the `c#` tag?

Comment: The edit totally changed your question. It would be only fair then to make this clear.

Comment: this is C++-CLI question.. not C#

Comment: It is applicable to C# as I guess!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one checks for `null` as well.

A TextBox->Text property will never be null but consider (C#):

```
string s1 = null;
string s2 = "";

string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1)    // true
string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2)    // true

s1 == ""    // false
s2 == ""    // true
```

The `IsNullOrEmpty()` function is just a handy helper to check 2 (error) conditions at once.

So your title is slightly off, this is about empty and null. Because:

```
string.Empty == ""     // true
```

---

A string is an object. `s1` and `s2` are not strings but references (pointers) to strings. `null` is a special reference value meaning 'not pointing to an object'. An empty string is a valid string object with length=0

Comment: `NULL` doesn't mean empty? What is the difference between `NULL` and empty exactly?

Comment: Adban, a string is an object. `s1` and `s2` are not strings but references (pointers) to strings. `null` is a special reference value meaning 'not pointing to an object'. An empty string is a valid string object with length=0

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that String::IsNullOrEmpty() also tests a string variable for null.
for example, both of these methods would return true:

```
public bool TestString(string theString){
  return String::IsNullOrEmpty(theString);
}

string emptyString; //currently a null object
TestString(emptyString); //returns true
emptyString = "";
TestString(emptyString); //also returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox1->Text=""` is assignment. You meant to write `TextBox1->Text==""`.

`String::IsNullOrEmpty()` tests true for `null` or the empty string, as its name indicates. As it happens, for your example, `TextBox1->Text` will never evaluate to `null`.

Comment: Downvote presumably because of the comment about `=` vs `==`? Question was edited!

Answer (score 1):

`IsNullorEmpty` will return true if the string is `null`. Other than that they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is an assignment, not an equality operator.

Looks like you confused `=` and `==` (btw. the single most prominent error source in C++).

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The first one checks for either of these:

```
string x = null //x is null, unassigned
string x = "" //x is a string, but with nothing in it.
```

The second only checks if

```
x == ""
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement return true if the string is null or empty the second only if the string is empty so, the first statement can be translated in :

```
if(TextBox1->Text == null ) || TextBox1->Text == "")
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line "if(IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1->Text))" can be written like this:

```
if (TextBox1->Text== null || TextBox1->Text == "")
```

The second statement is an assignment (And not a comparison) You're doing "x = value";
But if you made a typo, it means that you're not testing for null (compared to the first statement.